# How to get privacy setting (shared with) of posts and albums of friend

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to get the privacy setting of posts and albums of friends?
I can get the post of friend by using
https://graph.facebook.com/{friend_id}/posts  on Graph Explorer
but by inspecting the data I do not see any privacy field like the one in "me/posts"
If I look at the post
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=<>&set=at.<>&type=1
the "Shared With" attribute can tell what the privacy level is.
How can I read the attribute using Graph API or FQL?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy/

Comment: I can get privacy for albums from PRIVACY table but how do I get privacy settings for wall posts of friend. I can get privacy for wall posts of user from Graph API  uid/feed...return object contains privacy info but how do I get the same given uid of a friend of user?